# How to make Ajax Call when Browser not supporting Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, cross-browser

I have a problem. My browser not supporting Ajax call. Now I have to get data from Server without refreshing whole page. How can can get it. its not fixed data. Data will be dynamic . SO we need to make call to server with diff-2 params. Can we do it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'hacky' way to do it, but you also must verify that your browser support forms and iframes. I can't give you the complete example because the server involved, but I can describe you the scenario.

Scenario.

1. Create the form with the inputs which would hold your data. You can make the structured form which repeats your data domain model, or just add the text field where you will put your data in JSON format. Also it could be visible or not to the end user, it's your choice.
2. Create the hidden iframe on the page and give it the name and id attribute. This frame would hold the answer from your server and pass the data to main page.
3. Set the target attribute of the form to the iframes name. Now, when you will submit the form, the request would go to the server, but not the page would handle the response, but iframe will load it. Also, add named function to the global scope on main page, named like 'handlEResponse'. It will process the server data.
4. Your iframes answer should execute the JavaScript, and pass the data to the main page through window.parent.handleResponse callback.

P.S. 
Or make this in more easier way. Just create the script tag dinamically, with your parameters as a url querie i.e. 'https://mydomain/action?a=1&b=2', handle it on a server and generate JavaScript response which will execute needed functions on client side.